# Check which columns were INSERTed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know, when a row is inserted in a table, which columns were inserted **by the query**, and not implicitly set to null.

In such cases, the common solution is to use `update(col)` or columns_updated() in a trigger - but documentation clearly states:
`IF UPDATE returns the TRUE value in INSERT actions because the columns have either explicit values or implicit (NULL) values inserted.`
(and the same with columns updated).

Is there any way to draw the columns inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so, other than running a trace and inspecting the query. It's actually a great question since it went unanswered for seven hours. Maybe I'll add it to my battery of interview questions...

Answer (score 0):

Correct me If I am wrong. Are you thinking to do something like this?

```
INSERT INTO 
 TableName ( 
 ColumnName1,ColumnName2
 )
OUTPUT inserted.ColumnName1,inserted.ColumnName2
VALUES
 ('X','Y','Z');
```

or something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name, table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Nope. Your second solution returns the null`ability` of the column, where my columns are nullable. About your first one, the `inserted` table still has all the columns of the target table - even if you omit a column in your insert statement, the `inserted` table will have a null column, much like the original table.